# WebView detect button click event

Tags: android, button, webview

I am loading a web URL in webview. Like below :-

```
 mWebView                =       (WebView)findViewById(R.id.id__web_view);
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

How can I detect a button click event inside the loaded page. Say for example I want to show a toast "Clicked" when user clicks on "Images" tab after the search is done.(Please note that the detection of button click is one page ahead of the page that I loaded).

What I have tried:-
I did some research on how to do this, but none of these were fruitfull.
Below is one among them :-

```
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
{
  public void performClick()
  {
    // Deal with a click on the OK button
  }
}, "ok");

<button type="button" onclick="ok.performClick();">OK</button>
```

But this requires adding onclick in the html, I am not sure is it possible to do it on a 3rd party website. Please throw some light into the problem if any one has any clue.

Comment: inject javascript with `WebView.loadUrl` which would find the button somehow and add click listener

Answer (score 2):

Checkout below code.. its working fine for me

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }


    private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            view.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
            {
                @JavascriptInterface
                public void performClick() throws Exception
                {
                    Log.d("LOGIN::", "Clicked");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, "login");
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```